# Как правильно обработать css файл в загрузчике webpack 4 + mini-extract-css-plugin?

Tags: webpack4

Есть простейший конфиг для webpack 4

```js
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: './src/index.js',
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
        publicPath: '/dist',
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: '[name].css',
        })
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: '/node_modules/'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    'css-loader'
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
    devServer: {
        overlay: true,
    },
}
```

сss-файл импортируется в точку входа (index.js), необходимо его в продакшн-сборке вывести в отдельный файл main.css (c помощью mini-css-extract-plugin). Но возникает ошибка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тут [полная структура файлов](https://github.com/DazzRune/webpack4test)